# ASP.NET Web API - Response with status code "Redirect (302)" doesn't work on Internet Explorer 10

Tags: redirect, asp.net-web-api, request, response, internet-explorer-10

I create a request response with status code "Redirect (302)" without the URL to redirect.

```
private HttpResponseMessage Verify(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    ...

    return actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect, "Credentials not found!");
}
```

The response on Internet Explorer 10 return the status "(Abort)" rather than "Redirect" and in the other browsers (Chrome and Firefox) returns correctly.

Comment: Why would you return a response 302 without the URL?  302 status code should include a Location  header.

Comment: @JohnnyOshika because this RESTFull service is consumed by multiple applications and each has its own specific redirection.